# Show all arg passed with if-elseif statement

Tags: php, html, forms

I was build a code on PHP to get arguments by a form in HTML, this args must be compare to an array created earlier that contains the day of week in Spanish and English. The target of this web program is translate every day of weekend to english or spanish chosen by a checkbox.
I have many troubles because i want to show all days of week passed and with my code only have one that show.

This is my code. Its not very graceful but i am learning programing and i did before this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<body>  
<h2>PHP autovalidado</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Dia 1<input type="text" name="day1"><span class="error">*</span>
  Dia 2 <input type="text" name="day2"><span class="error">*</span>
 Dia 3 <input type="text" name="day3"><span class="error">*</span>
  Dia 4 <input type="text" name="day4"><span class="error">*</span>
 Dia 5 <input type="text" name="day5"><span class="error">*</span>
  Dia 6 <input type="text" name="day6"><span class="error">*</span>
  Dia 7 <input type="text" name="day7"><span class="error">*</span>
<br>Traducir al ingles o español:
 <input type="radio" id="ENG" name="translate" value="ES">
  <label for="ENG">Spanish</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="ES" name="translate" value="ENG">
  <label for="ES">English</label><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
$translatees  = "";
$translateeng  = "";
$day1  = "";
$day2  = "";
$day3  = "";
$day4  = "";
$day5  = "";
$day6  = "";
$day7  = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $translate = test_input($_POST["translate"]);
  $day1 = test_input($_POST["day1"]);
  $day2 = test_input($_POST["day2"]);
  $day3 = test_input($_POST["day3"]);
  $day4 = test_input($_POST["day4"]);
  $day5 = test_input($_POST["day5"]);
  $day6 = test_input($_POST["day6"]);
  $day7 = test_input($_POST["day7"]);

}
//Filtro de caracteres 
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
$dayweekes = array("Lunes",
"Martes","Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes",
"Sabado", "Domingo");
$dayweekeng = array("Monday",
"Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
"Saturday", "Sunday");
if ($translate == "ES"){
  if ($day1 == $dayweekeng[0]){echo $dayweekes[0];}
  elseif ($day2 == $dayweekeng[1]){echo $dayweekes[1];}
  elseif ($day3 == $dayweekeng[2]){echo $dayweekes[2];}
  elseif ($day4 == $dayweekeng[3]){echo $dayweekes[3];}
  elseif ($day5 == $dayweekeng[4]){echo $dayweekes[4];}
  elseif ($day6 == $dayweekeng[5]){echo $dayweekes[5];}
  elseif ($day7 == $dayweekeng[6]){echo $dayweekes[6];}
}elseif($translate == "ENG")
{if ($day1 == $dayweekes[0]){echo $dayweekeng[0];}
elseif ($day2 == $dayweekes[1]){echo $dayweekeng[1];}
elseif ($day3 == $dayweekes[2]){echo $dayweekeng[2];}
elseif ($day4 == $dayweekes[3]){echo $dayweekeng[3];}
elseif ($day5 == $dayweekes[4]){echo $dayweekeng[4];}
elseif ($day6 == $dayweekes[5]){echo $dayweekeng[5];}
elseif ($day7 == $dayweekes[6]){echo $dayweekeng[6];}}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Why would the language selection be a checkbox? You can logically only select one -- use a radio button in your form.  Beyond that, I don't understand how your code is _intended_ to behave.  Input `name`s with a trailing number usually indicates that braced, array syntax is probably appropriate.  Your question is needlessly bloated by the irrelevant CSS scripting.

Comment: I delete the CSS scripting and i change the code in the way that you told me. but the problem is the code only pass and show the first input which is monday. If you write the following days of week it doesnt translate

Comment: actually, i am with @mickmackusa on this one. You may want to make it radio or even just a simple select. Checkboxes can be multiple, while you wanna select simply one. Also, I suggest you proces `before` the main output.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect from the user.  Are they supposed to guess what the correct day name is (after the language conversion)?  You already know the two-way conversion.  Is this a test for the user?  I don't know why these 7 inputs are in the form.

Comment: Yes it is. If you set Monday, the form have to renturn Monday. If you set all days of week, the form have to return all days that you put. Its mandatory use arrays and a kind of switch button to swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to generate the 7 form fields (you are free to use client-side (like javascript/etc) or server-side (php) scripting to achieve this.

```
$maxInputs = 7;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxInputs; ++$i) {
    printf('Dia %d$1<input type="text" name="day[%d$1]"><span class="error">*</span>', $i);
}
```

When your form submits, you can access the `translate` and `day` elements of the POST payload.  Use a lookup array to translate perfectly spelled words.

```
// translated to Spanish by default
$trans = [
    "Monday" => "Lunes",
    "Tuesday" => "Martes",
    "Wednesday" => "Miercoles",
    "Thursday" => "Jueves",
    "Friday" => "Viernes",
    "Saturday" => "Sabado",
    "Sunday" => "Domingo"
];
if ($_POST['translate'] === 'ENG') {
    // translate to English
    $trans = array_flip($trans);
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxInputs; ++$i) {
    printf(
        '%s %d: "%s"',
        $_POST['translate'] === 'ENG' ? 'Day' : 'Dia',
        $i,
        $trans[$_POST['day'][$i] ?? ''] ?? ''
    );
}
```

This will attempt to read upto 7 input values from the submission.  If a given day field is left blank, then the null coalescing operators (`??`) will fallback to empty strings.

There will be hundreds of ways to do this task.  There is no real way of knowing what is the "best way".